# Creating a Registration and Login page in Visual basic

Tags: vb.net, webforms

I am trying to create a Username and Password Registration and login page in visual basic. I need the page to store the username and password in an array after entering it in the textbox. I also need the Username to be unique and only able to be put in the array once. After that with the login button I need it to display access granted after it can sense both the username and password in the arrays. Here is the code I have so far. I am able to enter the Username once, but after that no matter if the username is different or the same I get my error message box to pop up always.

```
Public Class WebForm1
    Inherits System.Web.UI.Page
    Public Shared Username(50) As String
    Public Shared password(50) As String
    Public Shared count As Integer = 0
    Public Shared count1 As Integer = 0
    Public Shared UN As String
    Public Shared PW As String
    Protected Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Dim UN As String
        Dim PW As String

        If TextBox1.Text = Nothing Then
            MsgBox("Please enter a Username to register", vbExclamation, "Error")
            Exit Sub
        End If

        If TextBox2.Text = Nothing Then
            MsgBox("Please enter a password to register", vbExclamation, "Error")
            Exit Sub
        End If

        For i As Integer = 0 To count - 1
            If Username(i) = UN Then
                MsgBox("This Username has already been used! Please enter a new Username", vbExclamation, "Error")
            End If
        Next

        Username(count) = UN
        count += 1

        password(count1) = PW
        count1 += 1

    End Sub

    Protected Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click

        For i As Integer = 0 To count - 1
            If Username(i) = UN & password(i) = PW Then
                MsgBox("Access Granted")
            End If
        Next


    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: You can't use `MsgBox` in WebForms.

Comment: Is this a homework assignment? If so, you should tag it as such.

Answer (score 0):

To check if a textbox is empty you use the `String.IsNullOrEmpty` or `String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace` methods

```
If String.IsNullOrEmpty(TextBox1.Text) Then
    MsgBox("Please enter a Username to register", vbExclamation, "Error")
    Exit Sub
End If
```

You never assign any value to the `UN` and `PW` variables.
Change the local declarations of `UN` and `PW` in `Button1_Click` to

```
Dim UN As String = TextBox1.Text
Dim PW As String = TextBox2.Text
```

`&` concatenates strings, use `AndAlso` or `OrElse` to do boolean operations.

```
If Username(i) = UN AndAlso password(i) = PW Then
    MsgBox("Access Granted")
End If
```

You also declared `UN` and `PW` both globally and locally in `Button1_Click`. Any changes you make to them in `Button1_Click` with these local declarations in place will not update the global `UN` and `PW`

```
Public Shared UN As String
Public Shared PW As String
```

remove these global `UN` and `PW` declarations and in `Button2_Click` declare `UN` and `PW` locally.

```
Protected Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
    Dim UN As String = TextBox1.Text
    Dim PW as String = TextBox2.text
    For i As Integer = 0 To count - 1
        If Username(i) = UN AndAlso password(i) = PW Then
            MsgBox("Access Granted")
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Using a fixed array to store information a user can infinitely add items to will eventually lead to an out of bounds access in the array.
A `Dictionary(Of String, String)` would be better suited for your situation.